# magnetization of single ion from 10 ion system

Tags: condensed-matter

I am simulating some quantum spin lattice (in one dimension) system having 5 qubits (ions). 
Can you suggest how to calculate single ion magnetization?
also can we have total magnetization, if yes then how to calculate that?
if possible suggest some references

Comment: We need more information about exactly what you are trying to simulate (and how) to be able to answer your questions

Comment: I am trying to simulate, on quantum simulator, a crystal having 5 ions (in simulation particles are equivalent to qubits) and after some iteration i want to measure magnetization of single qubit.